# ios any UIView property allows me to set buttons underneath the view in-active?

Tags: ios, uiview, properties

For ratation and iAd and design reason, I don't want to use modal view to present a message (not via alert view either). I plan to bring up a screen-sized label up and show the message there. That can be done. However, there are a bunch of buttons (ABCD etc) underneath the big label and those buttons are logged in different status and they are clickable. Ideally a user would read the label and disable it via a specified button (X). However, users could click anywhere they want and more than often they will hit those buttons underneath the big label and screw up things. When the big label shows up, only X is visible, and ABCD etc are invisible. Now my question is there any UIView property or whatever property that I can set so that buttons that are invisible are not functioning, although they might be enabled.

Comment: `overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `alpha` property on your buttons to 0. This will have 2 effects:

1) make the buttons invisible

2) make them ignore the user input

When you need to re-enable the buttons, just set their alpha to 1 again.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know the effect of number 2 of property alpha. Thanks. Give you a green check.